# CSS Global Class Issue with Child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a global class for an html

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="content"></div>

</div>
```

and the CSS is

```
.div { width:auto; display:block }


.content {  width:100px;  height:50px; }
```

On the .content div, i do not need "display:block" class. But Its applying on Runtime.
i Have given dispay:inherit; but it doesn't work. Is there any Other Way for Removing the Display Style ?

Comment: .div will only apply to elements with a class of div, did you mean to use `div { }`?

Comment: there's no way to remove inherited styles other than to explicitly overwrite them

Comment: Do you want to say that "display : block;" property applying in your div at run time? If it's applying at runtime that's mean it may be inline property on target div in that case you can remove it at runtime by applying anyother value for display. Or if you want to use CSS then you should have to use "!important" for it. So that it can ignore inline css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.div { width:auto; display:block }
```

this might not be working....for the above provided html cos there is not div named class

what you can do is

```
.content {  width:100px;  height:50px; display:inline}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.content {  width:100px;  height:50px; display: inline; }
```

or another display property

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
.content {  width:100px;  height:50px; display:inline }
//or display:none or whatever your standard default is
```

`inline` is what the value is by default, see [MDN Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display).